# Django | Request muestra datos pero ListView no muestra ningún dato

Tags: django, django-models, django-urls

Mediante una función request, me muestra toda una lista de datos correctamente:

```
def station_list(request):
    stations = Station.objects.filter().order_by('name')
    incidencias = Incidencia.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'station/station_list.html', {'stations': stations, 'incidencias': incidencias})
```

En cambio si lo adapto a una ListView, no me muestra ningún dato:

```
class StationList(ListView):
    template_name = 'station/station_list.html'
    model = Station
    def station_list():
        stations = Station.objects.filter().order_by('name')
        incidencias = Incidencia.objects.all()
        return render(request,'station/station_list.html', {'stations': stations, 'incidencias': incidencias})
```

Template:

```
{% for station in stations %}
        <th scope="row">{{ station.codigo }}</th>
{% endfor %}
```

¿Qué sucede? Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

La clave está en mostrar en el template utilizando object_list en vez de stations:

```
{% for station in object_list %}
    <th scope="row">{{ station.codigo }}</th>
{% endfor %}
```